# OpenGL ES 2.0 Crash on glDrawElements after unbinding VBO

Tags: android, opengl-es, crash, segmentation-fault

First I should say that I am using running this on a emulator of the pixel with Android API 27 but I was also getting the same crash on Android API 26.

I been just trying to draw a 2-D sprite and animate it. I have a thread running concurrently to the render loop (in GLSurfaceView and GLSurfaceView.Renderer) updating a VBO with different texture coordinates in a sprite sheet. But that, from what I can tell isn't where the problem is from.

Basically all I can tell is that glDrawElements after I bind and unbind my VBO crashes, specifically the unbind. Specifically it is a null pointer dereference error. This problem doesn't happen when I unbind my Element Buffer Object though.

EDIT:I just posted this and I realized I forgot to mention that after some quick reading on glBindBuffer I found:

> The value zero is reserved, but there is no default buffer object for
>   each buffer object target. Instead, buffer set to zero effectively
>   unbinds any buffer object previously bound, and restores client memory
>   usage for that buffer object target (if supported for that target).

Could the part about restoring memory be the cause of this? If it is then how would I go about unbinding it.

Here is the code for Sprite.java:

```
package com.matthew.beatclimber;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.opengl.Matrix;

import android.content.Context;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * Created by matthew on 10/28/17.
 */
/*
Note to self:
This can be done to bind a attribute location to a literal
GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vPosition");
 */
public class Sprite
{
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;
    private Timer animateTimer;
    private SpriteSheet spriteSheet;
    private int[] vbo = {0}, ebo = {0}, texture = {0};
    private int vertexShader, fragmentShader, program;
    static float[] vertices = {
            -16.0f, 16.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, /*Tex Coords*/ -1.0f, 1.0f, //Top Left
            -16.0f, -16.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,               -1.0f, -1.0f, //Bot Left
            16.0f, -16.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,                1.0f, -1.0f, //Bot Right
            //-1.0f, 1.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f, /*Tex Coords*/ -1.0f, 1.0f, //Top Left
            //1.0f, -1.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f,                1.0f, -1.0f, //Bot Right
            16.0f, 16.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,                 1.0f, 1.0f //Top Right
    };
    private static final short[] order = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};
    private float[] model = new float[16];
    static float[] ortho = new float[16];
    char[] infoLog = new char[512];
    private static final String vertexShaderCode =
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "attribute vec2 TexCoords;" +
                    "varying vec2 texCoords;" +
                    "uniform mat4 ortho;" +
                    "uniform mat4 model;"+
                    "void main() {" +
                    "   gl_Position = ortho * model * vPosition;" +
                    "   texCoords = TexCoords;" +
                    "}";
    private static final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform sampler2D tex1;" +
                    "varying vec2 texCoords;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "   gl_FragColor = mix(texture2D(tex1, texCoords), vec4(texCoords, 0.0, 1.0), 0.2);" +
                    "}";
    public Sprite(int screenWidth, int screenHeight)
    {
        //Set model equal to a identity matrix
        Matrix.setIdentityM(model, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(model, 0, screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2, 0);
        Matrix.scaleM(model, 0, 32, 32, 0);




        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(order.length * 2);
        dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indexBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
        indexBuffer.put(order);
        indexBuffer.position(0);

        //Create shader program
        vertexShader = OpenGLES31Activity.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        fragmentShader = OpenGLES31Activity.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);
        program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        int[] success = new int[2];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, success, 0);
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, success, 1);

        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);

        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vPosition");
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "TexCoords");

        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
        if((success[0] == GLES20.GL_FALSE))
        {
            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            String info = GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader);
            System.out.println("ERROR: VERTEX: " + info);
        }
        if ((success[1]  == GLES20.GL_FALSE))
        {
            GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            String info = GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader);
            System.out.println("ERROR: FRAG: " + info);
        }
        //Create Buffer Objects (Vertex and Element Buffer Objects)
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, vbo, 0);
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, ebo, 0);

        //Bind Objects
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo[0]);

        //Write Data
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer.capacity() * 4, vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer.capacity() * 2, indexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        //Unbind objects
        //GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        //GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        animateTimer = new Timer();
    }
    public synchronized void draw()
    {
        //Use Shader Program
        GLES20.glUseProgram(program);
        //////////////////////Configure Attribute (Core OpenGL ie: in)//////////////////////////
        //Get Attribute Locations
        //int attribLocationPos = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
        //int attribLocationTex = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "TexCoords");

        //Enable Vertex Attribute Array
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 24, 0);

        //Tex Coord Attribute
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 24, 16);

        //Bind Objects
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo[0]);

        //int[] i = new int[1];
        //int[] j = new int[1];

        //GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, i, 0);
        //GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, j, 0);
        //System.out.println(i + " " + j);

        //Set model matrix uniform to model
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "model"), 1, false, model, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "ortho"), 1, false, ortho, 0);

        //Texture Stuff
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

        //Draw Square
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, order.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        //GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        //Disable Vertex Attribute Array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        //GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        //Stop using program
        //GLES20.glUseProgram(0);
    }
    public void createTextureSpriteSheet(Context context, int resourceID, int spriteWidth, int spriteHeight, int sheetWidth, int sheetHeight, int frame)
    {
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceID);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                // Ignore.
            }
        }
        //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("R.raw.blobbosheet.png      \
        ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bitmap.getByteCount());
        data.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(data);
        System.out.println("Bitmap: " + bitmap.getWidth() + " " + bitmap.getHeight());
        data.position(0);
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texture, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        //GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        spriteSheet = new SpriteSheet(sheetWidth, sheetHeight, spriteWidth, spriteHeight, 8);

        float[] texCoords = spriteSheet.getSpriteCoords(frame);
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("TexCoord: " + i + " is : " + texCoords[i]);
        }
        spriteSheet.setFrame(frame);

        //Update Tex Coords
        vertices[4] = texCoords[0];
        vertices[5] = texCoords[1];
        vertices[10] = texCoords[2];
        vertices[11] = texCoords[3];
        vertices[16] = texCoords[4];
        vertices[17] = texCoords[5];
        vertices[22] = texCoords[6];
        vertices[23] = texCoords[7];

        updateVBO();
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }
    public void switchSprite(int frame)
    {
        float[] texCoords = spriteSheet.getSpriteCoords(frame);
        spriteSheet.setFrame(frame);

        //Update Tex Coords
        vertices[4] = texCoords[0];
        vertices[5] = texCoords[1];
        vertices[10] = texCoords[2];
        vertices[11] = texCoords[3];
        vertices[16] = texCoords[4];
        vertices[17] = texCoords[5];
        vertices[22] = texCoords[6];
        vertices[23] = texCoords[7];

        updateVBO();
    }
    public void nextFrame()
    {
        float[] texCoords = spriteSheet.nextFrame();

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("TexCoord: " + i + " is : " + texCoords[i]);
        }
        //Update Tex Coords
        vertices[4] = texCoords[0];
        vertices[5] = texCoords[1];
        vertices[10] = texCoords[2];
        vertices[11] = texCoords[3];
        vertices[16] = texCoords[4];
        vertices[17] = texCoords[5];
        vertices[22] = texCoords[6];
        vertices[23] = texCoords[7];

        updateVBO();
    }
    public void animate(int startFrame, int framesPerSec, final int numbOfFrames)
    {
        switchSprite(startFrame);
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {
            int count = 0;
            public void run()
            {
               nextFrame();
               count++;
               System.out.println("Animate Thread Going!");
               if(count == numbOfFrames)
               {
                   System.out.println("Animate Thread Canceled");
                   cancel();
               }
            }
        };
        animateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000 / framesPerSec);
    }
    public synchronized void updateVBO()
    {
        System.out.println("In updateVBO()");
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        vertexBuffer.clear();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices).flip();
        float[] test = new float[vertexBuffer.capacity()];
        vertexBuffer.get(test);
        for(float i : test)
        {
            System.out.println(i + ", ");
        }
        vertexBuffer.clear();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices).flip();
        for(int i = 4; i < 23; i += 6)
        {
            System.out.println("TexCoord: " + i + " is : " + vertices[i]);
            System.out.println("TexCoord: " + i + " is : " + vertices[i + 1]);
        }
        System.out.println(vertexBuffer.capacity() * 4 + " " + vertexBuffer.remaining());
        GLES20.glBufferSubData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertexBuffer.capacity() * 4, vertexBuffer);
        //GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer.capacity() * 4, )
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
}
```

and the code for my renderer:

```
package com.matthew.beatclimber;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;

import android.app.Activity;
/**
 * Created by matthew on 10/28/17.
 */

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    Sprite sprite;
    float[] orthoProjection = new float[16];
    Context context;
    public MyGLRenderer(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        sprite = new Sprite(1080, 1704);
        sprite.createTextureSpriteSheet(context, R.drawable.blobbosheet, 32, 32, 256, 32, 0);

        sprite.animate(0, 2, -1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        Matrix.orthoM(orthoProjection, 0, 0, width, 0, height, -1, 100);
        Sprite.ortho = orthoProjection;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10)
    {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        System.out.println("Drawing");
        sprite.draw();
    }
}
```

Also here is what it dumps into the log:

```
11-04 17:50:41.569 13651-13670/com.matthew.beatclimber A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10 in tid 13670 (GLThread 490), pid 13651 (hew.beatclimber)
11-04 17:50:41.606 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-04 17:50:41.606 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:8.1.0/OPM1.171004.001/4376136:userdebug/dev-keys'
11-04 17:50:41.606 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
11-04 17:50:41.606 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
11-04 17:50:41.606 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG: pid: 13651, tid: 13670, name: GLThread 490  >>> com.matthew.beatclimber <<<
11-04 17:50:41.606 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
11-04 17:50:41.606 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
11-04 17:50:41.606 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000010  ebx 9eaf3be4  ecx 00000008  edx 8f4000ea
11-04 17:50:41.606 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     esi 00000010  edi 00000000
11-04 17:50:41.606 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
11-04 17:50:41.606 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     eip ab72b33c  ebp 8ff7c5c8  esp 8ff7c588  flags 00010202
11-04 17:50:41.907 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
11-04 17:50:41.907 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0001a33c  /system/lib/libc.so (memcpy+732)
11-04 17:50:41.907 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00021cd0  /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so (glUtilsPackPointerData+480)
11-04 17:50:41.907 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0003bb98  /vendor/lib/libGLESv2_enc.so ((anonymous namespace)::glVertexAttribPointerData_enc(void*, unsigned int, int, unsigned int, unsigned char, int, void*, unsigned int)+184)
11-04 17:50:41.907 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000286c4  /vendor/lib/libGLESv2_enc.so (GL2Encoder::sendVertexAttributes(int, int, bool, int)+1124)
11-04 17:50:41.907 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000167ce  /vendor/lib/libGLESv2_enc.so (GL2Encoder::s_glDrawElements(void*, unsigned int, int, unsigned int, void const*)+958)
11-04 17:50:41.907 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00009c3f  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so (glDrawElements+79)
11-04 17:50:41.907 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00099c16  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android_glDrawElements__IIII(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int, int, int, int)+38)
11-04 17:50:41.907 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00e82a36  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5fc000) (android.opengl.GLES10.glClearColorx [DEDUPED]+182)
11-04 17:50:41.907 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00642032  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
11-04 17:50:41.907 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00116009  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+265)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0032143f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+335)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0031a6a4  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+836)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0062927a  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+282)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00633021  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14497)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 002f392b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 002fa1e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+231)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 0031a68a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+810)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00627a44  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+756)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 00632ea1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14113)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 002f392b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 002fa1e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+231)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 0031a68a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+810)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 00628c0f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1647)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 006330a1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14625)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 002f392b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 002fa1e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+231)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 0031a68a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+810)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 0062905c  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+428)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 00632fa1  /system/lib/libart.so (artMterpAsmInstructionStart+14369)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #29 pc 002f392b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+539)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #30 pc 002fa0cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*)+139)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #31 pc 006175ef  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1311)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #32 pc 00647f2d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #33 pc 00641e62  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 00115fdf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+223)
11-04 17:50:41.908 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #35 pc 00544aeb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+91)
11-04 17:50:41.909 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #36 pc 00545fb8  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+744)
11-04 17:50:41.909 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #37 pc 0057512f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1487)
11-04 17:50:41.909 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #38 pc 00071445  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53)
11-04 17:50:41.909 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #39 pc 000205db  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+75)
11-04 17:50:41.909 13678-13678/? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 0001ec16  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
11-04 17:50:42.190 1484-1484/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_04
```

Comment: Is your second thread executing any OpenGL commands? Note, that a OpenGL context can only be used by one thread at a time.

Comment: My second thread is a TimerTask being run by a java.util.Timer (I assume it's just a another thread) which is calling glBindBuffer and glBufferSubData but after commenting out those calls the same crash happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of operations is a bit messed up. When setting vertex attribute pointers, one has to bind the buffer first and then setup the pointer.

```
public synchronized void draw()
{
    //Use Shader Program
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

    //Enable Vertex Attribute Array
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 24, 0);

    //Tex Coord Attribute
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 24, 16);

    //Bind Index Buffer
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo[0]);
    ...
}
```

The error manifests when adding the buffer unbinding code because otherwise the correct buffers are still bound from the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely quick answer!